# Powerful Debuggers for Django

Tags: django, debugging

The Django debugger is absolutely dreading and finding errors is a daunting task.

Are there any third party Django debuggers out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pydevd](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) plugin for eclipse supports debugging code run from outside the IDE. I find it works great with Django.

It's simple to use  - start the debugger from eclipse, then add the line `import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()` and execution will break at that line, allowing you to step through etc from eclipse.

To debug code on a remote machine, include the ip address of the machine running eclipse as an argument to `settrace()` (ie `import pydevd;pydevd.settrace('10.0.0.68')`).

Obviously the pydevd module will neeed to be on your pythonpath.

For installation instructions check the [docs](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Django debuggers, but [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) by JetBrains is an awesome Python IDE with a built-in debugger.  I've been using it for over 2 years (previously a decade long user of their awesome IntellJ Java IDE) for Django work and it's been worth every penny paid.

Comment: I totally agree, PyCharm is great for Django debugging, I think it compares very nicely to Pydev.  It allows you to run your server and your tests in debug mode with breakpoints and all.  You also get the benefits of autocomplete and pretty intelligent inspection of your apps, models, URLs, etc.